# Filling a matrix with element by element operations using a function

Tags: matlab

I have a 3x1 matrix which  I want to store the results of an algebraic expression. Previously, I was storing the results of the algebraic expression using different inputs separately, but I want to be able to fill the matrix with 1 calculation / call while having multiple inputs into the function. This is my thinking process so far.

Algebra Expression (Pseudo-Code Not Matlab)

```
result = x * ( y + z ) ^ 2
```

My Inputs ( I was thinking to make this a vector as well ? )

```
first_input_x = 10;
first_input_y = 5;
first_input_z = 3;

second_input_x = 3;
second_input_y = 5;
second_input_z = 8;

third_input_x = 10;
third_input_y = 6;
third_input_z = 1;
```

What I was doing before is

```
first_result  = first_input_x  * ( first_input_y + first_input_z ) ^ 2;
second_result = second_input_x * ( second_input_y + second_input_z ) ^ 2;
third_result  = third_input_x  * ( third_input_y + third_input_z ) ^ 2;
```

My Matrix

```
matrix_results = zeros( 3, 1 );
```

Just to recap, I want to be able to write

```
matrix_result = *some automated way to perform my expression using the inputs and store them in correct order, first would be location 1 of the matrix, second location 2, etc.*
```

I'm trying to self-learn matlab and I'm not sure how this can be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is **element-wise operations**. They are very commonly used in Matlab. See the documentation for [`.*`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) and [`.^`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html):

```
x = [10; 3; 10];
y = [5; 5; 6];
z = [3; 8; 1];
result = x .* ( y + z ) .^ 2; % note the dots. Addition does not require the dot
```

Comment: in this case the result would be the result matrix correct? Which would end up being 3x1 as well?

Comment: @JohnWayne I'm not sure what you mean. See the variable `result` in my example and check if its values are what you need